# NSCopy GKGameModel doesn't copy player objects correctly

Tags: swift, gameplay-kit, nscopying

I am trying to use swift NSCopy to do a deep copy of a GKGameModel's object, including all players and their wallet reference (containing Integers representing their cash).

Using Swift playgrounds I try to credit all copied players with $100, but leave original player objects intact.

However, I notice that the code impacts original player objects too.

At a high level, the code should show:

```
Game class, a GKGameModel
Player class, a GKPlayerModel
Wallet class, handles very basic player's Int transactions.
```

Goals:

- Copy the game class, all players and their linked wallet class
- Credit the copied players with $100.
- The original players should still have $0

Code follows:

```
// Uses Swift playground

import GameplayKit

class Game : NSObject, GKGameModel{
    override var description: String {
        return ("game: \(String(describing: self.players))")
    }

    // -- GKGameModel code follows --
    var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]?
    var activePlayer: GKGameModelPlayer?


    func gameModelUpdates(for player: GKGameModelPlayer) -> [GKGameModelUpdate]? {
        return nil
    }

    func unapplyGameModelUpdate(_ gameModelUpdate: GKGameModelUpdate) {
    }


    func apply(_ gameModelUpdate: GKGameModelUpdate) {

    }

    func setGameModel(_ gameModel: GKGameModel) {
        guard let inputModel = gameModel as? Game else {
            assertionFailure("No game model initialised")
            return
        }
        guard let players = inputModel.players else {
            assertionFailure("No players initialised")
            return
        }

        self.activePlayer = inputModel.activePlayer
        self.players = players
    }

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        print ("copying game obj!")
        let copy = Game()
        copy.setGameModel(self)
        copy.players = self.players  // if I do not include it, copy.players is nil
        return copy
    }
}

class Player : NSObject, NSCopying, GKGameModelPlayer {
    override var description: String {
        return ("name: \(name), cash: $\(cash), wallet: $\(wallet.balance)")
    }

    internal var playerId: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print ("Set playerId = \(self.playerId)")
        }
    }
    var name: String
    var cash : Int = 0

    var wallet : Wallet = Wallet()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        print ("copying player!!") // this code is never reached
        let copy = self
        copy.wallet = self.wallet.copy(with: zone) as! Wallet
        return copy
    }
}

enum WalletError : Error {
    case mustBePositive
    case notEnoughFunds
}

fileprivate protocol WalletDelegate {
    var balance : Int { get }
    func credit(amount: Int) throws
    func debit(amount: Int) throws
}

class Wallet : NSCopying, CustomStringConvertible, WalletDelegate {
    public private(set) var balance: Int = 0

    func credit(amount: Int = 0) throws {
        try canCredit(amount: amount)
        self.balance += amount
    }

    func debit(amount: Int = 0) throws {
        try canDebit(amount: amount)
        self.balance -= amount
    }

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        print ("copy wallet")  // this code is never reached
        let copy = Wallet()
        return copy
    }
}


extension Wallet {
    private func canCredit(amount: Int) throws {
        guard amount > 0 else {
            throw WalletError.mustBePositive
        }
    }

    private func canDebit(amount: Int) throws {
        guard amount > 0 else {
            throw WalletError.mustBePositive
        }

        guard self.balance >= amount else {
            throw WalletError.notEnoughFunds
        }
        guard (self.balance - amount >= 0) else {
            throw WalletError.notEnoughFunds
        }
    }
}

extension Wallet {
    var description: String {
        return ("Balance: $\(self.balance)")
    }
}

let players : [GKGameModelPlayer] = [ Player.init(name: "Bob"), Player.init(name: "Alex"), Player.init(name: "John")  ]
let game = Game()
game.players = players

func copyTheGame() {
    let copiedGame = game.copy() as! Game

    print ("BEFORE:")
    print ("Original: \(String(describing: game))")
    print ("Copied: \(String(describing: copiedGame))")
    print ("----")

    if let copiedPlayers = copiedGame.players {
        for p in copiedPlayers as! [Player] {
            do {
                p.cash = 100 // try to manipulate a class variable.
                try p.wallet.credit(amount: 100)
            } catch let err {
                print (err.localizedDescription)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    print ("AFTER:")
    print ("Original: \(String(describing: game))")
    print ("Copied: \(String(describing: copiedGame))")
    print ("----")
}

copyTheGame()
```

In my output, I get the following:

```
copying game obj!
BEFORE:
Original: game: Optional([name: Bob, cash: $0, wallet: $0, name: Alex, cash: $0, wallet: $0, name: John, cash: $0, wallet: $0])
Copied: game: Optional([name: Bob, cash: $0, wallet: $0, name: Alex, cash: $0, wallet: $0, name: John, cash: $0, wallet: $0])
----
AFTER:
Original: game: Optional([name: Bob, cash: $100, wallet: $100, name: Alex, cash: $100, wallet: $100, name: John, cash: $100, wallet: $100])
Copied: game: Optional([name: Bob, cash: $100, wallet: $100, name: Alex, cash: $100, wallet: $100, name: John, cash: $100, wallet: $100])
----
```

Issues:

- The player copy code never gets hit
- The wallet copy code never gets hit
- The $100 credited affects both the original and copy.

How do I ensure that any changes I make are only to the copied game object, and not the originals?

With thanks

---

Update:

I've been able to force the copy by looping through all the player objects, but I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it.

If I change the copy function in the game class to:

```
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Game()

        let duplicate = self.players?.map({ (player: GKGameModelPlayer) -> GKGameModelPlayer in
            let person = player as! Player
            let copiedPlayer = person.copy(with: zone) as! Player
            return copiedPlayer
        })

        copy.players = duplicate

        return copy
    }
```

This lets me make a duplicate of all the player objects, also; the copy() function in the player and wallet class get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to resolve the issue by force copying reference objects, arrays or child objects

ie:

```
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Game()

        let duplicate = self.players?.map({ (player: GKGameModelPlayer) -> GKGameModelPlayer in
            let person = player as! Player
            let copiedPlayer = person.copy(with: zone) as! Player
            return copiedPlayer
        })

        copy.players = duplicate

        return copy
    }
```